# NoReverseMatch в Django, когда я пытаюсь обновить объект модели

Tags: django

Я написал `View` для обновления записи в базе данных,но когда я пытаюсь перейти на страницу с редактированием записи,я получаю сообщение об ошибке:

**Ошибка:**

[image]

Выводил в списке записей айди каждой, он есть у каждой записи.

Я написал один в один из существующего `View` для другой модели, поэтому я не понимаю, в чем ошибка. Как я могу это исправить?

**urls.py**

```
 path(
    'keys/<int:key_id>/',
    views.UpdateKeyView.as_view(),
    name='update_key'
),
```

**views.py**

```
 class CreateKeyView(
    SuccessMessageMixin,
    CustomPermissionRequired,
    CreateView
):

    model = ApiKey

    template_name = 'db_visual/create_key.html'

    form_class = KeyForm

    permission_required = (
        'db_visual.add_keys',
    )

    success_message = "Ключи %(description)s успешно создан!"

    def get_success_url(self):
        print(self.object.id)
        return reverse_lazy(
            'update_key',
            kwargs={'key_id': self.object.id}
        )



  class UpdateKeyView(
    SuccessMessageMixin,
    CustomPermissionRequired,
    UpdateView
):
    model = ApiKey
    pk_url_kwarg = 'key_id'

    template_name = 'db_visual/update_key.html'

    form_class = KeyForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('keys')

    permission_required = (
        'db_visual.change_key',
    )

    success_message = "Ключ <a href='%(url)s'>%(description)s</a> " \
                      "успешно изменен!"

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return self.success_message % dict(
            cleaned_data,
            url=reverse_lazy(
                'update_key',
                kwargs={'key_id': self.object.id}
            ),
        )
```

**HTML-код create_key**

```
{% for key in api_keys %}
        <tr>
            <td class="min-col">
            <a href="{% url 'update_key' key_id=key.id %}">
                    {{ key.description}}
            </a>
            </td>
            <td class="min-col">{{ key.open_key }}</td>
            <td class="min-col">{{ key.secret_key }}</td>
            <td class="min-col">
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-link"
                   href="{% url 'update_key' key_id=key.id %}">
                    <i class="far fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

**HTML-код update_key**

```
<form action="{% url 'update_key' key_id=key.id %}"
  method="post" class="col-12" id="key_form">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="card">
    <h2 class="card-header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                Ключи для {{ key.description }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </h2>
    <div class="card-body">
        {% include 'db_visual/key_form_body.html' %}
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Сохранить"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Model.py**

```
class ApiKey(models.Model):
    open_key = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    secret_key = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    restrict_ip = models.BooleanField()
    ip = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, null=True), size=8, blank=True, null=True
    )
    valid_to_date = models.DateField()
    restrict_methods = models.BooleanField()
    allowed_methods = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True),
        size=8, blank=True, null=True
    )
    forbidden_methods = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True),
        size=8, blank=True, null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = '"processing"."api_key"'
```

UPD: Когда я создаю новый объект и пытаюсь выполнить функцию `get_success_url`, я получаю ту же ошибку, но`self.object.id` содержит айди созданной записи.

UPD2: Выяснил, что в `update_key` не передаётся объект модели, но непонятно почему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Была ошибка в названии объекта... В `view` для просмотра списка ключей, которого не было в вопросе, был задан `context_object_name = 'apikey'`:

```
class KeysView(
    LoginRequiredMixin,
    CustomPermissionRequired,
    ListView,
):
    # Переопределение из MultipleObjectMixin
    model = ApiKey
    context_object_name = 'apikey'
```

А обращался в шаблон я к `key.id` вместо `apikey.id`.

Comment: А можете прямо в ответе написать, мол было такое название, а по ошибке указал такое?

Comment: @gil9red, да, думаю так лучше, обновил.